# Null dates being converted to 1900-01-01 in Azure Data Factory

Tags: date, azure, null, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I am bringing data from different databases to Blob storage in Azure by Data Factory, the problem is all the date values turn into 1900-01-01 when Null.

Do you have any suggestion what to do in order to keep the null value?

Thanks

Comment: Is the date column in Data Factory nullable? What type are you using for the column? How are the null values coming in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Custom Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities) to achieve this.  In your Custom Activity you will have access to the source and destination `Linked Services` and `Datasets`. You can transform the data the way you want. You have to write your own transformation logic.

You will not have much control over data transformation if you are using Data Factory's `Copy Activity`.

Another Approach is to use [Data Factory Management APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactories.datafactorymanagementclient?view=azuremgmtdatafactories-4.12.1). This way you can create output dataset structure as per the input data. In this approach you will have full control over the Data Movement and Transformations.